# How do you call all list elements in a specific format in Python?

Tags: list, printing, format

I am trying to build an Employee Management System and am having difficulties printing all of the elements entered into a list in a specific format. I can get my last entry to print but if I have multiple list elements, it won't display them on the screen.  What am I doing wrong in my for loop or is there a better way to display them all in the format I have outlined?

```
employee_info = [ ]

while True: # While loop created to make the script constantly run
    counter = len(employee_info) # Counter created so that the user will know how many entries there are

    print('There are', '(', (int(counter)), ')', 'employees in the system.\n')

    add_new = input('Would you like to add a new employee to the system or view all employee entries in the system?\
    To add an employee, type: "ADD". To view all employees currently in the system, type: "VIEW ALL."\n') #Added option to add an employee or to view all employees currently the system

    if add_new == 'ADD':
        while True: # Loop created to input employees with option to quit
            employee_index = [input('Employee Name\n'), input('Employee SSN\n'), \
            input('Employee Telephone Number ***Entered as (555)555-5555*** \n'), input('Employee Email\n'), input('Employee Salary ***Entered as $xxxx***\n')] 
            employee_info.append(employee_index)
            more_employees = input('Would you like to add another employee? Y or N.\n')
            if more_employees == 'Y':
                continue
            elif more_employees == 'N':
                break

    elif add_new == 'VIEW ALL':
        for x in employee_info:

            print('            -----------------', employee_index[0], '-----------------\n')
            print('SSN:', employee_index[1], '\n')
            print('Phone:', '(' + employee_index[2][0] + employee_index[2][1] + employee_index[2][2] + ')' + employee_index[2][3] + employee_index[2][4] + employee_index[2][
            5] + '-' + employee_index[2][6] + employee_index[2][7] + employee_index[2][8] + employee_index[2][9], '\n') 
            print('Email:', employee_index[3], '\n')
            print('Salary:', '$' + str(employee_index[4]), '\n')
            print('            ----------------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: Could you describe specifically what doesn't work? You may get better results if you can boil this code down to the actual issue you are encountering.

Comment: Hi Rob, I think that I have come up with a better code but my problem now is that I can't get the script to print all of my user input list items in my format.  It will only print the last input entered versus all of my list items.  How do I do that?

Comment: I figured it out.  I should have stated for employee_index in employee_info: in order for it to display all of the entries!

Comment: in elif replace employee_index with x